# C# .net Windows application: select multiple rows in datagridview and pass all the selected rows to another datagridview in another form

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

I have a datagridview in Windows Form, let's say it datagridview1 with fixed column (SAY ID,NAME,AGE) and in it's first column (i.e ID) on cellBeginEdit, I open another form which also contain datagridview which is loaded with data, lets say it datagridview2 and it also have many column say ID,JOB,NAME,AGE,TYPE.

I want to select multiple rows in datagridview2 and on enter pass all the selected rows from datagridview2 to datagridview1 in specific columns.

I tried many things but none worked.
 here is my code

from 1st form  - datagridview1 CellBeginEdit :

private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)

```
    {

        dr = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        if (e.ColumnIndex == dr.Cells["grid_bill"].ColumnIndex)

        {

            if (dr.Cells["grid_module"].Value.ToString().Equals("SALES"))

            {

                var form = new frmSalesInvoiceMaster(); //i am calling frmSalesInvoiceMaster where on load i have provided datatable as a datasource to datagridview

                form.ShowDialog();

            }

        }

    }
```

[image of my datagridview , it contains 2 datagridview AND both are in differenct forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ2rI.png)

form 2 i.e frmSalesInvoiceMaster

here what i want is , user can select multiple rows from datagridview of form 2 and i want to fetch the multiple selected rows from form 2 datagridview and hide this form 2 and show all the selected rows of form2 in datagridview1 of form 1 in specific column.

Comment: Hi, it helps if you post a minimal code version of your setup as [edit] of your question.

Comment: without any samples of your code, i can provide you only simple answer with general solution: 1. obtain selected rows. 2. store it in some collection type like Datatable. 3. create public property on parent form with proper setter code. 4. set value of parent property in child form. that's all in very general.

Comment: (Pro-tips: this may have been downvoted for the lower-case mobile-phone writing, the urgent begging, the please-help begging and the txtspk. This is not a chatroom, and volunteers are here in their spare time. Please make a good effort to ask questions in a readable and clear fashion, and be aware that your question is not more important than any others here).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i have provided sample of code. and guys i am sry about writing URGENT.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have event dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit on form one:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        var result = f.ShowDialog();
        if(result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            List<Person> selection = new List<Person>();
            f.GetSelection(selection);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = selection;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }
        f.Dispose();

    }
}
```

Now, first I check if edited column is the first one (ID) - you don't have to do that if you don't care.

Next I create form2 and show it modally. Whan user clicks OK button on form2, it returns DialogResult.OK.

Next I create a list of records, that will be fed with selection from form2 -> GetSelection.

When I have selection I can fill dataGridView with it. Here I'm using BindingSource - you can do something else.

And now form2:

First I load some data:

```
void LoadData()
{
    List<Person> data = new List<Person>();
    Person p = new Person { Id = 1, Age = 20, Job = "Consultant", Name = "John" };
    Person p2 = new Person { Id = 2, Age = 22, Job = "Programmer", Name = "Steven" };
    Person p3 = new Person { Id = 3, Age = 22, Job = "Manager", Name = "Alice" };
    Person p4 = new Person { Id = 4, Age = 30, Job = "Analytic", Name = "Mark" };
    Person p5 = new Person { Id = 5, Age = 32, Job = "Analytic", Name = "Gregory" };
    Person p6 = new Person { Id = 6, Age = 32, Job = "Tester", Name = "Hugh" };

    data.Add(p);
    data.Add(p2);
    data.Add(p3);
    data.Add(p4);
    data.Add(p5);
    data.Add(p6);

    bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = data;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

And the most interesting method is GetSelection wich is really simple:

```
public void GetSelection(List<Person> result)
{
    var rows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Person p = rows[i].DataBoundItem as Person;
        if (p != null)
            result.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Of course don't forget to add OKButton that will set DialogResult to OK.

Comment: when i add ok button in another form , its showing the error that the form should not be  visible and it should be closed first . and i closed  the form by calling close(); but same error

Comment: You do something very wrong. Do you open the form using ShowDialog as I have written?